# Use Object Destructuring without declaration an put it into a function

Tags: javascript

I'm coding a React App and just curious: is there a way to use object destructuring without a declaration (using let, const, var) and right away put it into a function?

I have tried this but failed.
`console.log('visible', {visible}: this.state);`

My state for example:

```
this.state = {
    visible: true
}
```

From (2 lines)

```
let {visible} = this.state;
console.log('visible', visible);
```

To (1 line)

```
console.log('visible', {visible} = this.state);
```

Comment: Just use no destructuring at all but simply access the property?

Comment: Thank you but, I want to use it in advance like {visible1, visible2} = this.state

Comment: In the code in your question, you had only a single property. What do you actually want? If you want to pass multiple values to `console.log`, then no you won't have a choice but either use multiple property accesses or a separate destructuring declaration.

Answer (score 2):

you can use `console.log('visible', this.state.visible);`. To use the destructing, you have to use two lines

Comment: Keep simple things simple :-)

Comment: Yes, I know this but I want more like {visible1, visible2} = this.state

Answer (score 0):

If you're writing your own function you can destructure the arguments directly like this (TypeScript):

```
const someFunc = ({visible}:SomeState) => {//etc.}
```

If you don't use TypeScript you don't need the `:SomeState`

Comment: Using const is using declaration and I don't want to use it in this example.